# Resize of d3.js barchart

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg, resize, window-resize

I am studying d3.js library and svg. And I have problems resizing a simple barchart as a function of svg-wrapper's width (or window's width), in my case it is div.barchart.

What do I want to accomplish? I need:

- height of svg = const (in my case I made it as a function of quantity of objects in my array of data)
- width of svg = variable - a function of current div.barchart's width(when user resizes window of browser).

I am asking for help how to do that. My code is below or here http://codepen.io/Balzzac/pen/ZWEOGa:

html/css

```
<div class="barchart"></div>

.barchart
{
    width: calc(100%);
    height: auto;
}
```

JS

```
 var myArrayOfObjects = [
    {kind: 1,  name: "A", y: 400},
    {kind: 1,  name: "B", y: 400},
    {kind: 2,  name: "C", y: 350},
    {kind: 2,  name: "D", y: 350},
    {kind: 2,  name: "E", y: 350},
    {kind: 3,  name: "G", y: 300},
    {kind: 4,  name: "I", y: 250},
    {kind: 4, name: "J", y: 250},
    {kind: 5,  name: "K", y: 200}
];

var lengthOfArray = myArrayOfObjects.length;
var width = $(".barchart").width();
var height = Math.round(lengthOfArray * 40);
var barPadding = 0.1;
//margin
var marginLeft = 120;
var marginTop = 0;
var marginRight = 200;
var marginBottom = 0;
var margin = { left: marginLeft , top: marginTop, right: marginRight, bottom: marginBottom};

//data
var yColumn = "name";
var xColumn = "y";
var colorColumn = "kind";

//size of canvas
var innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
var innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select(".barchart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


var group = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xAxisG = group.append("g")
.attr ("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")"); 
var yAxisG = group.append("g")
.attr ("class", "y axis");

//scales
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range( [0, innerWidth]);
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerHeight], barPadding);
var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
//axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
.ticks(5)                   
.outerTickSize(0);         
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
.outerTickSize(0);         


function render(data)
{
    xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[xColumn]; })]);
    yScale.domain(data.map( function (d){ return d[yColumn]; }));

    //xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);
    //bind data
    var bars = group.selectAll("rect").data(data);
    //enter
    bars.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand());
    //update
    bars
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y",     function (d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]); })
        .attr("width", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
        .attr("fill" , function (d) {return colorScale(d[colorColumn]);});

    //exit
    bars.exit().remove();

}

render(myArrayOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myArrayOfObjects = [
 {kind: 1,  name: "A", y: 400},
 {kind: 1,  name: "B", y: 400},
 {kind: 2,  name: "C", y: 350},
 {kind: 2,  name: "D", y: 350},
 {kind: 2,  name: "E", y: 350},
 {kind: 3,  name: "G", y: 300},
 {kind: 4,  name: "I", y: 250},
 {kind: 4, name: "J", y: 250},
 {kind: 5,  name: "K", y: 200}
];

var lengthOfArray = myArrayOfObjects.length;
var width = $(".barchart").width();
var height = Math.round(lengthOfArray * 40);
var barPadding = 0.1;
//margin
var marginLeft = 120;
var marginTop = 0;
var marginRight = 200;
var marginBottom = 0;
var margin = { left: marginLeft , top: marginTop, right: marginRight, bottom: marginBottom};

//data
var yColumn = "name";
var xColumn = "y";
var colorColumn = "kind";

//size of canvas
var innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
var innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//html part
var svg = d3.select(".barchart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width) //strange resize with 100%
.attr("height", height);
//.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height) //does strange resize
//.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid meet"); //does strange resize


var group = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var xAxisG = group.append("g")
.attr ("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")"); 
var yAxisG = group.append("g")
.attr ("class", "y axis");

//scales
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range( [0, innerWidth]);
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerHeight], barPadding);
var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
//axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
.ticks(5)                   // Use approximately 5 ticks marks.
.tickFormat(d3.format("s")) // Use intelligent abbreviations, e.g. 5M for 5 Million
.outerTickSize(0);          // Turn off the marks at the end of the axis.
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
.outerTickSize(0);          // Turn off the marks at the end of the axis.


function render(data)
{
 xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[xColumn]; })]);
 yScale.domain(data.map( function (d){ return d[yColumn]; }));

 //xAxisG.call(xAxis);
 yAxisG.call(yAxis);
 //bind data
 var bars = group.selectAll("rect").data(data);
 //enter
 bars.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand());
 //update
 bars
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y",     function (d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]); })
  .attr("width", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
  .attr("fill" , function (d) {return colorScale(d[colorColumn]);});

 //exit
 bars.exit().remove();

}

render(myArrayOfObjects);
function initializeWH(){
 width = ($(".barchart").width());
 height = Math.round(lengthOfArray * 40);
 innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
 innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 xScale = d3.scale.linear().range( [0, innerWidth]);
 yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerHeight], barPadding);
 console.log(width);
 console.log(height);
}
$(window).on('resize', function(){
 initializeWH();
 render(myArrayOfObjects);
});
```

```css
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 border: none;
}
.barchart
{
 width: calc(100%);
 height: auto;
 background: #eee;
/*  outline: 1px solid black; */
 
}

.axis text
{
 font: 16px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line
{
 fill: none;
 stroke: #ddd;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

/* .x.axis path, .x.axis line
{
 stroke: none;
}
 */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="barchart"></div>
```

Here you need to do few things, those are
1) on window resize you need to calculate current width and height of the div, and from those values calculate innerWidth and innerHeight then update the scales xScale and yScale.
2) Now generate the barchart with the updated width and height.

To perform those tasks I've added code

`function initializeWH(){
    width = ($(".barchart").width());
    height = Math.round(lengthOfArray * 40);
    innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range( [0, innerWidth]);
    yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerHeight], barPadding);
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
}
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    initializeWH();
    render(myArrayOfObjects);
});`

Hope you understood.

Code updated http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzKLEz